# Rowstore oriented SQL storage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that for a rowstore oriented table, how the record(s) are actually stored on the hard disk or in behind will be

```
Column1AColumn2AColumn3A|Column1BColumn2BColumn3B|Column1CColumn2CColumn3C
```

If there are 3 records, and 3 columns, then the each row will be stored on the disk as a consecutive value, and with a separator between rows.

I just want to learn more about SQL operators, when SQL operator retrieve row(s) from the disk, from a consecutive row how can it know how to separate between columns as there are no commas or anything related?

Appreciate everyone's help. Thanks.

Comment: For the FixedVar format the fixed width columns are stored together and it is easy for fixed width because the offsets are also fixed, variable length columns have the offsets stored in the row https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/. If compression is used a different scheme is used

Comment: Adding to what @MartinSmith said, also see [anatomy of a page](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/).

Comment: @MartinSmith so do you mean that because each field/column has a predetermined width or length, and so the operator will use this information to get the correct column required?

Comment: For fixed length columns, yes. The offsets for these can be seen in `sys.system_internals_partition_columns`